# Can't import whois in .py file, but can in shell

Tags: python, python-import, python-idle, whois, pywhois

I have recently installed `whois`.

When I try to import the `whois` module in a `.py` file I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. However, when I give the import command in a Python shell the problem does not occur, and the module imports as expected. Each time I am using the same command:

`import whois`

When using the shell I can get more information about the location the module was imported from:

```
import whois
whois
<module 'whois' from 'C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\whois\\__init__.py'>
```

Why would a python shell in the same directory as the `.py` file have different behavior than said file? hat can I do to rectify it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show `sys.path` in the failed instance and information about where exactly the module is installed.

Comment: So figure out why `C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages` is not in `sys.path`, and probably show how exactly you invoke Python when you get that.

Comment: If you have multiple pythons installed, then you likely have whois installed for just one of them.  If it is the same python binary (`print(sys.executable)`), then path needs to be examined.

Comment: "I have recently installed whois." You may want to start by explaining how you installed it exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from .folder import whois
```

if doesn't work - try to create in that folder empty file `__init__.py`, restart ide or what and try again